# Como gravar dados de um form em banco de dados convertendo os campos para JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, formulário, post

Tenho um form qualquer, exemplo:

```
<form action="confi.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p><input type="text" name="nome" value="nome">
   <p><input type="text" name="email" value="email">
   <p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Eu gostaria de gravar esses campos (como um JSON) em uma tabela.

**confi.php**

```
//minha conexão com o banco

$sql = "INSERT INTO `banco`.`tabela`(`json`) VALUES ('$json')";
```

A minha dúvida é, como eu pego e converto os campos/valores preenchidos no form em um arquivo JSON para gravar na tabela dessa forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**@UPDATE**

Consegui montar o `JSON` com o `json_encode` como sugerido.

Porém quando o registro chega no banco, o valor é "Array".

```
$myArr = array("nome" => $_POST['nome']
        , "email" => $_POST['email']);
json_encode($myArr);
```

Insert no banco

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tabela`(`json`) VALUES ('$myArr');";
```

Tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra inserir o real valor do json?

Comment: Embora talvez você prefira usar seu banco de dados, você pode tentar o MongoDB, um database de JSON que não utiliza SQL. Caso você queira guardar os dados em JSON como mostrou no exemplo, `nome:value  e-mail:value`, vale mais a pena utilizar o MongoDB. Veja aqui: http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=706

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou dar uma estudada em MongoDB, porém de momento não consigo mudar isso por envolver outras aplicações

Comment: ``json_encode()`` retorna a string JSON! Então ficaria ``$myArr = json_encode($myArr);``. É bom lembrar que isso é um padrão bem comum em PHP: funções não alteram o argumento que você passa pra elas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só usar a função `json_encode($_POST)`

[Documentação da função json_enconde](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Lembrando que, conforme a documentação, a função `jason_encode()` não altera o array que você passar pra ela, só retorna a string JSON. Ou seja:

```
$myArr = array("Um" => 1, "Dois" => 2, "Três" => 3);
$json = json_encode($myArr);
```

Mas se quer guardar dados em `JSON`, conforme comentado na sua pergunta, talvez seja melhor usar o `MongoDB` ou outros bancos de dados `NoSQL`

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de respondida, vou adicionar isto à discussão:

O JSON (JavaScript Object Notation, porque tem o formato de um objecto JS) não é um formato de arquivos, primeiro. Sim, um formato de padrão aberto de dados.

Depois, armazenar dados como JSON no MySQL seria ir contra o intuito de um sistema gerenciador banco de dados relacional (muito embora, alguns chamem os banco de dados NoSQL de "relacionais não normalizados", o que para mim não soa bem). Mesmo assim, o [MySQL tem suporte para o JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) desde a versão 5, assim como o PostgreSQL (que, nesse quesito pelo menos, tem mais funções). E o [**SQL Server 2014+**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn921897.aspx) também, o que eu esperei muito.

Embora você estivesse melhor usando MongoDB, CouchDB, Cassandra, MarkLogic, outros, *você ainda pode armazenar os dados JSON como string no banco de dados relacional normalizado*.

Um código simples para armazenar o **$_POST** no banco de dados como **JSON** é como segue:

```
try {
    // Conexão com o banco de dados e seus atributos
    $conexao = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco_de_dados", 'usuario', 'senha');

    $conexao->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Query com o placeholder :json         
    $query = 'INSERT INTO tabela (json) VALUES (:json)';

    // Usando prepared statements, porque é mais seguro e melhora a performance
    $insert = $conexao->prepare($query);

    // Diz pro MySQL que o parametro representado pelo placeholder :json na query é uma string, convertendo $_POST em uma string JSON
    $insert->bindParam(':json', json_encode($_POST, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Executa a query
    $insert->execute();

    // Verifica se a inclusão foi feita
    $linhas_afetadas = $insert->rowCount();

    // XXX Aqui você pode mudar o número de acordo com o número de linhas que voc~es espera serem afetadas
    if($linhas_afetadas == 1) {
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Dados inseridos com sucesso'));
    }


} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => $ex->getMessage);
}
```

O código não foi testado, mas pode ser facilmente utilizado, já que usa um modelo bem conhecido com PDO (é, use sempre [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)).

Comment: Muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento.